# Error loading for Core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I try to use CoreData to persist for some data. The data is downloaded from url and it is a Json which contains a set of user details. I try to parse json and convert the data into my NSManagedObjectModel subclass, called "User". However, the app breaks without any explanation. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
//var friend = [User]()

func loadUpdateData(){

self.refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()

let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString

let url = NSURL( string: "http://192.168.0.101/index.php?method=updateData&id=1" )

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = checkList!

var updateQueue = NSOperationQueue()
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: updateQueue, completionHandler: { (response, recievedData, error) -> Void in

    if error == nil && (recievedData != nil) {

        let dataString = NSString(data: recievedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let readableData = dataString?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var updatedFriendList = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(readableData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)! as [NSDictionary]

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            for (var index=0; index<updatedFriendList.count; index++) {
                User.insertNewUser(self.objectContext!, newUserDict: updatedFriendList[index])   **//it seems app crashes at this line is being executed.**
            }
            self.objectContext?.save(nil)

            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        })

    }else{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let _ = self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        })
    }
})    
}
```

and for the "User" class:

```
class User: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var userName: String
@NSManaged var userNickName: String
@NSManaged var sex: NSNumber
@NSManaged var birth: NSDate
@NSManaged var userID: NSNumber
@NSManaged var userAvatar: NSData
@NSManaged var numOfTarget: NSNumber
@NSManaged var latestUpdateTime: NSDate


class func insertNewUser(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, newUserDict: NSDictionary) {

    let user = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as User

    user.userID = newUserDict.valueForKey("userID") as NSNumber
    user.userName = newUserDict.valueForKey("userName") as String
    user.latestUpdateTime = newUserDict.valueForKey("latestUpdateTime") as NSDate
    user.numOfTarget = newUserDict.valueForKey("numOfTarget") as NSNumber
    user.userNickName = newUserDict.valueForKey("userNickName") as String
    user.userAvatar = newUserDict.valueForKey("userAvatar") as NSData
    user.sex = newUserDict.valueForKey("sex") as NSNumber
    user.birth = newUserDict.valueForKey("birth") as NSDate

    moc.save(nil)
}
```

--update error snapshot--
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x19317b268:  movz   x16, #328
0x19317b26c:  svc    #128
0x19317b270:  b.cc   0x19317b288               ; __pthread_kill + 32
0x19317b274:  stp    fp, lr, [sp, #-16]!
0x19317b278:  mov    fp, sp
0x19317b27c:  bl     0x19316259c               ; cerror_nocancel
0x19317b280:  mov    sp, fp
0x19317b284:  ldp    fp, lr, [sp], #16

### 0x19317b288:  ret

2015-04-09 22:47:27.488 Incentive[355:78244] -[Incentive.User setNumOfTarget:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702c1c70
2015-04-09 22:47:27.492 Incentive[355:78244] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Incentive.User setNumOfTarget:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702c1c70'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18229e59c 0x1929f40e4 0x1822a5664 0x1822a2418 0x1821a6b6c 0x1000a2678 0x10009b79c 0x10009c294 0x181c86f34 0x183157508 0x1830a8c94 0x18309861c 0x18315a26c 0x1004e0df0 0x1004eb854 0x1004e4120 0x1004ed75c 0x1004eef18 0x1932152e4 0x193214fa8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Well, it should break somewhere when running in the debugger, so that is your first clue.

Comment: Can you define "the app breaks"?  Breakpoint?  Symptoms?

Comment: @JohanKool, the breakpoint doesn't stop at specific line. I have updated the statement when app breaks. Please see the updated statements above. Moreover, I tried to execute the codes line by line, it seems the bug happens at the line:     for (var index=0; index<updatedFriendList.count; index++) {
                User.insertNewUser(self.objectContext!, newUserDict: updatedFriendList[index])   **//it seems app crashes at this line.**
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the explanation:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Incentive.User setNumOfTarget:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702c1c70'
```

It means that the User class doesn't know about setNumOfTarget:. Check if your CoreData model actually properly defines it.

Comment: Actually my "User" class doesn't have a property called "setNumOfTarget". It does have a property called "numOfTarget". Are they related? If so, what is the relationship of them?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how should  the CoreData model DEFINE a class? Thanks!

Comment: I see, you are right. It really is because of my carelessness! I made wrong name in my models... Thanks.